# Postgresql - 100% sure to use SSL connection with server?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, psql

is it possible to check (as not rooted user/SQL question) to check, if my connection from client to server uses SSL  (my destination server cas uses both - secured and not secured connection)?

Comment: The answer depends on the PostgreSQL client you are using.

Comment: for any libpq client, and for PgJDBC, `sslmode=require` or preferably `sslmode=verify-full`. Other clients may vary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as of 9.5:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-SSL-VIEW

> The pg_stat_ssl view will contain one row per backend or WAL sender
>   process, showing statistics about SSL usage on this connection. It can
>   be joined to pg_stat_activity or pg_stat_replication on the pid column
>   to get more details about the connection.

```
t=# set role notsu ;
SET
Time: 9.289 ms
t=> select * from pg_stat_ssl where pid = pg_backend_pid();
  pid  | ssl | version | cipher | bits | compression | clientdn
-------+-----+---------+--------+------+-------------+----------
 43767 | f   |         |        |      |             |
(1 row)

Time: 10.846 ms
t=> \du+ notsu
                  List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of | Description
-----------+------------+-----------+-------------
 notsu     |            | {}        |
```

the above shows my connection is not SSL